# What French children songs do most native French speakers know?

Tags: apprentissage

I do not know any French,
but I'm trying to learn French together with my kids.
I've found that my kids like to listen to and sing French children songs.
Therefore, I decided that
this is a good method for us to learn some French.

I found a list of 358 songs on YouTube
created by [Comptines et chansons](https://www.youtube.com/user/comptines/featured).
The problem is that this is a very large number of songs,
so I would like to know,
out of all of these songs,
which are the most popular or well-known songs
among children who are French native speakers?

As an example, I will give a list of children songs
that I believe most English speakers must know:

- Happy Birthday
- If You're Happy and You Know It
- The Wheels on the Bus
- The Alphabet Song (A B C D E F G...)
- Twinkle Twinkle Little Star
- Mary had a Little Lamb
- etc

Comment: This is really the sort of question that can produce endless lists and is not really about the French Language. This site will give you titles of songs taht I expect all French children (and their aprents) know, but the liks are broken, you'll have to look for the words&music through a search engine. Easy to find. If looking for more you search for "*chansons enfantines* " and "*comptines*" (nursery rhymes). I will collect a few useful links and leave them in chatroom.

Comment: A list of websites that collect the most popular ones. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35838368#35838368

Comment: As Laure says, here's a contribution to an endless list, but ... I recently greatly enjoyed two children's albums by the Franco-Manitoban singer Daniel Lavoie. They won't be well-known, I don't think, but they're good and quite sweet: [Le bébé dragon](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/album/b%C3%A9b%C3%A9-dragon/id259084906) and [Le bébé dragon 2](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/album/le-bebe-dragon-vol.-2/id259085911). And here's [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6pnVZuKJyg) to two full songs from the latter on YouTube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Au clair de la lune
- mon beau sapin
- Do, do, l'enfant do
- Cadet Rousselle
- Fais dodo, Colas mon petit frère
- Meunier tu dors
- un kilomètre à pied, ...